# Does WatchService.take() block other operations on WatchService?

Tags: watchservice

I'm wondering if it is possible to register more directories or close a WatchService after `take()` has been called in a different thread. Will a `ClosedWatchServiceException` then be thrown in the thread that called `take()`? Or will the other operations not have effect until a change event happens and `take()` returns? Thanks